# cambiar color de renglon tabla html Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Quiero saber si es posible cambiar a color rojo los renglones de la tabla al encontrar un valor en el arreglo de datos. Estos datos son extraidos de un archivo .json.

```
function DatosJsonTabla() 
{
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#facturas').DataTable( 
        {
            "ajax": 
            {
                "url": "json/comparador.json",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "columns": 
            [
                { "data": "folio" },
                { "data": "fecha" },
                { "data": "total" },
                { "data": "sia" },
                { "data": "sat" },
                { "data": "tipo" },
                { "data": "moneda" },
                { "data": "sucursal" }
            ]
        } );
    } );      
}
```

Este es el codigo de la tabla donde mando a llamar los datos con el id=facturas

```
<table id="facturas" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead bgcolor="#041C33">
            <tr style="color:#FFFFFF";>
                <th>Folio</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>SIA</th>
                <th>SAT</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Moneda</th>
                <th>Sucursal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Este es mi archivo comparador.json de donde obtengo los datos y los mando a la tabla.

```
[
    {
        "folio":"131253",
        "fecha":"10-04-2019",
        "total":775.00,
        "sia":"Cancelada",
        "sat":"Activa",
        "tipo":"Nota de Credito",
        "moneda":"MXN",
        "sucursal":"Hermosillo Bodega"
    },
    {
        "folio":"458004",
        "fecha":"08-03-2019",
        "total":153.00,
         "sia":"Activa",
         "sat":"Cancelada",
         "tipo":"Factura",
        "moneda":"MXN",
        "sucursal":"Hermosillo Bodega"
    }
]
```

Espero de su ayuda, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `fnRowCallback` para esto y evaluar la celda

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            if ( aData[3] < 40 ) //si la edad es menor de 40
            {
                $('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#F44336' );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```